# How do i create a function that creates list and adds members to those list based on user input?

Tags: python

I've created a Class call groups- The user is suppose to give the "group" a name and add members to it as they see fit. Its a Class function that would create a list and add members to that list.
The code i currently have does produce an empty list.

I've tried using .append(), .join(), .insert()

```
class group:
    def __init__(self, name, member):
        self.name = name =[]
        self.member = member.join(name)


test_one = group("church", "john")
print (test_one.name)
print(test_one.member)
```

I expected the output of 
Church = ["john"]

Comment: I don't think you understand how `join` works.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be assigning a list to `name`, you should assign the list to `self.member`.

```
class group:
    def __init__(self, name, member):
        self.name = name
        self.member = []
        self.add_member(member)

    def add_member(self, member):
        self.member.append(member)

test_one = group("church", "john")
print (test_one.name)
print(test_one.member)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/QqiSUK)

You could also write `self.member = [member]` in `__init__()`, but this is more modular -- only one method needs to know how to add a member.

Comment: Thank you much sir. I shall continue my research.

Comment: Strange I'm not getting an error...but this is the new output <main__.group object at 0x03E139F0

Comment: What is the output from? That's the expected output if you do `print(test_one)`

Comment: @Clarke- I added a link to a demo showing it works correctly.